# Sort rows with angular-ui-sortable (drag&drop)

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui-sortable

I'am using angular-ui-sortable is it possible to drag&drop (sort) the columns of a table with angular-ui.sortable. I only can sort the rows :(

Here is my example for the rows:

```
<tbody ui-sortable="sortableOptions" ng-model="categoryValue.selectedFields">
   <tr ng-repeat="device in tables[categoryKey].data">
       <td ng-repeat="(selectedFieldKey, selectedField) in categoryValue.selectedFields">{{device.data[selectedField]}}</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: AFAIK ui-sortable should only contain one ng-repeat. Please check https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable